# How to compile and run using GCC?

Tags: 14.04, compiling, gcc

I'm taking [this course from Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/software-security/) and they asked us to have at least some knowledge in C .

So as they asked us to use GCC And Ubuntu , I installed both of them , I then [followed this tutorial from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiaiZmWxcck) but I had no luck running or compiling.

In fact , while I'm trying to rename my Empty file to "test.c" the icon of the file doesn't seem to change to letter "C" like his file.

As for compiling , I tried doing this :

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

but I had no chance and I received the following error code :

```
gcc: error: test.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
```

I can't understand why it says there is no such file or directory while I can clearly see the file on the Desktop.

Comment: if the file is on your desktop, then you need to `cd Desktop` before you can run that command...

Comment: Are you sure ? as the terminal was giving "USername@username-desktop" ?

Comment: that looks like the name of your computer. The command will only work if the file is in the current working directory, so you have to `cd` to that directory first. By default when you open a terminal you are in your home directory and `Desktop` is a subdirectory of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc` will not search your computer for the file named `test.c`; it must be present in your *working directory* in your shell session.

`$ pwd` to see what your current working directory is.

`$ ls` to list the files in your working directory.

Comment: pwd says "home/username" which I assume means I'm not in the desktop , and ls isn't showing the test.c logically.

IF I try to do "cd desktop" It says that there is no such file or directory as well ?

Comment: `cd Desktop`.  File names are case-sensitive on your linux system; `desktop` would not be the same as `Desktop`;  `test.c` is not the same file as `Test.c` or `test.C`